# warning: Can't mass-assign protected attributes (using paperclip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, paperclip, nested-attributes

I think attachment doesn't saving in the database because of this warning. I tried different variants of attr_accessible attributes, but I always get this warning or error "unknown attribute: upfile". So, my code:

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :attaches, :as => :uploadable, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :title, :body, :commentable, :attach_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attaches
end
```

attach.rb:

```
require 'paperclip'
class Attach < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :uploadable, :polymorphic => true

  has_attached_file :upfile
  attr_accessible :upfile
end
```

warning:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"m+81lxu25R0Fu2bHUJthIBU265V+kDo+6wcL3BcFwoc=", "post"=>{"title"=>"sdfsdfsdf", "body"=>"sdfdsfsdfsd", "commentable"=>"0", "upfile"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003d35290 @original_filename="www.rubyonrails (1).com", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[upfile]\"; filename=\"www.rubyonrails (1).com\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120201-2498-1ef2jve>>}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: upfile
```

If I change attr_accessible, for example, to ":title, :body, :commentable, :upfile", I get this error:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"m+81lxu25R0Fu2bHUJthIBU265V+kDo+6wcL3BcFwoc=", "post"=>{"title"=>"dfsdf", "body"=>"sdfsdfsdf", "commentable"=>"0", "upfile"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f011c0559f0 @original_filename="www.rubyonrails (1).com", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[upfile]\"; filename=\"www.rubyonrails (1).com\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120201-2498-qvfih5>>}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: upfile):
```

Using ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.0, paperclip 2.5.2

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in views. Need to use fields_for for nested resources:

```
<%= f.fields_for :attaches do |a| %>
  name: <%= a.text_field :name %>
  attach: <%= a.file_field :upfile %>
<% end %>
```

And no attr_accessible in post.rb and attaches.rb